# Error appears while running the program in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I installed the Unity Hub. But one error message appears while running the program.

How can I solve this problem ?

[image]

I cannot hold on my works because of this problem.

Comment: please read [ask] and improve your question -  we have no more access then you do, but we have the added disadvantage of the fact we cant see what you do, so you have to explain it all to us.

Comment: You must login in Unity Hub, that will generate a license.

Comment: I installed unity. I have seen a warning that is called "no valid unity editor license found. please activate your license" while running the program. I use 2023.1.5f1 version of unity.

Comment: well did you make one? did you activate it? we arent mind readers

Comment: @SezginKaragülle What happens when you open the [Unity Hub](https://unity.com/download)?

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't have a license, hence quite straightforwardly you should search for "How to activate a unity hub license or something"

if you are using unity hub 3.x:

1. Go to the rounded icon on the top left to access your account setting
2. Go to "Manage licenses", it should show a popup like this

[image]

3. add a license on the "add" button on the top right corner